How does the use of Elliptic Curve Pairings in ZK-Proofs not make it vulnerable to the MOV attack?
The key size in an Elliptic Curve Group where the discrete log problem is hard is much smaller than the key size in a Multiplicative Group of a Finite Field in which the discrete log problem is hard because there is no attack like Index Calculus in an Elliptic Curve Field.
The Menezes-Okamoto-Vanstone (MOV) attack transforms a Discrete Log problem in an Elliptic Curve Group into a Discrete Log Problem in a Finite Field's Multiplicative Group.
The suggested mitigation for the MOV attack is to use an Elliptic Curve where the embedding degree is not small
A few questions about this mitigation

If the embedding degree is small, then does it mean that you cannot finding a paring for the curve or does it mean that if you do find a pairing, the finite field which is the output of the pairing will be one where the discrete log problem will remain hard. A related question is what exactly is pairing un-friendly curve - is it one where you cannot find a pairing or is it one where the output group will be field where the multiplicative discrete log problem is hard?

Many ZK-Proofs like Groth16/PLONK etc use EC Pairing for the proof. Does this mean that the output group has a hard discrete log problem or does it mean that it doesn't matter for the proof - i.e. the proof doesn't depend on the untractability of the ECDLP?




For a pairing-friendly curve, the pairing maps to an extension field of sufficient size that the discrete logarithm is harder than the security parameter, while the computation of the pairing itself is not too onerous. The best index calculus attack on the extension field is typically the extended tower number field sieve (XTNFS) attack by Kim and Barbulescu. A good survey of the attack costs for various pairing-friendly construction is give by Barbulescu and Duquesne.

I'v not seen "pairing-unfriendly" in common usage, but would take it to mean a curve where the computation of the pairing consumes more resources than are desirable.

For Zero-Knowledge constructions, one should use pairing-friendly curves where the discrete logarithm is hard in the finite field where the pairing takes values. People typically use the costing from Barbulescu and Duquesne above.

